# Agregar footer a tabla con ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una tabla y quiero agregarle dinamicamiente un footer a esta para que siempre se vea aunque scrollee la tabla. Este es mi codigo:
HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 tab-pane fade" id="stockCC" style="height: 241px; overflow:auto">
                        <table runat="server" id="tablaStockC" class="table table-condensed table-striped fixed" style="margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:0px;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width:10%">Dep.</th>
                                    <th style="width:80%">Plataforma</th>
                                    <th style="width:10%; text-align: right">St</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tableStockCentral">
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot id="footStockCentral">
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Y asi probe haciendo desde C# la interacción con el footer:

```
                        TableFooterRow filaTotal = new TableFooterRow();
                        HtmlTableCell celdaCodigoTotal = new HtmlTableCell();
                        HtmlTableCell celdaTextoTotal = new HtmlTableCell();
                        HtmlTableCell celdaTotalPlataforma = new HtmlTableCell();
                        celdaCodigoTotal.InnerText = "";
                        celdaTextoTotal.InnerText = "Total";
                        celdaTotalPlataforma.InnerText = totalSucursal.ToString();
                        filaTotal.Cells.Add(celdaCodigoTotal);
                        filaTotal.Cells.Add(celdaTextoTotal);
                        filaTotal.Cells.Add(celdaTotalPlataforma);
                        tablaStockCentral.Rows.Add(filaTotal);
```

El problema es que me da error al querer agregar la celda a la fila (con la instruccion **filaTotal.Cells.Add(celdaCodigoTotal);**.

Este es el error que me da:

> cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell'

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Que error te da?. indícalo en la pregunta por favor.

Comment: Listo Rafael, disculpa no me di cuenta de ponerlo. Es porque estoy tratando de guardar un tipo de HtmlTableCell en un TableCell

Comment: Porque armas la tabla de esta forma en lugar de usar el GridView ? no esta bueno armar la tabla como lo estas realizando